# Searching keywords in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Here's an example of the customer codes:

C000000123
C000000456

If I input C123 in the search box, "C000000123" will automatically display.
9 numbers are fixed.

Please help me, a short sample was shown to me but I don't get it.

```
function test(key, num, digit) {

    let retStr;
    xxxx (condition)
    retun retStr;

}
```

here's an elaboration:

**
input:123
output:A00000123

input:1
output:A00000001

input:99999
output:A00099999
**

here's the detailed demand:

Since it takes time and effort to enter the management number “alphabet + numeric value 9 digits” on the search screen, when the alphabetic number and the number excluding the leading 0 are entered, it is automatically complemented so that it becomes 9 padded with zeros.

sorry i'm very very new to programming in javascript

Comment: Is there a specific question you'd like to ask?

Comment: how do i use javascript to make a program according to the conditions stated above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
May be what you want...
Please test it and tell if its what you want.

```
function getOutput(input){
  var str=input.substring(1,input.length);
  var padd0=9-str.length;  
  var zr="000000000";
  var zrsub=zr.substring(0,padd0);
  var output=input[0]+zrsub+""+str;
 return output;
}
```

//Example: Call it like (NB any letter can be used):

```
getOutput("C123");   //or
getOutput("D123");
```

Comment: how can i connect the html search function in this? Sorry i'm really low level beginner.

Comment: Let's me also ask, where you want output to be displayed?

Comment: Ok, but this could cause conflict! because, it's on the same interface where you write and also you get output at the same time. May be there must be extra button to click on order to get entered output.

Comment: sorry i meant text box. like if i input c123 and click an OK button for example then the output displays. how do i do that

Comment: Ok download zip from link https://www.dropbox.com/s/p4l1der9nxl3r5z/SearchByKey.zip?dl=1 extract then open with browser. And tell if it works. That is html file based on your codes you provided. I have added button and output box.

Comment: brother thank you very much @wailenb! your code is very accurate

Comment: hey brother sorry for another question but how can i store "000000000" into a parameter? for example `function getOutput(input, num){` put zeros in the "num" parameter?

Comment: Do you mean inverse of previous function?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.endsWith` in js which takes a string and a search string and returns true if the specified string ends with the search string.

This function takes an array of customer ids and a search string and returns the matching customer id

```
function searchCustomer(customers, searchString) {
    return customers.find(customer => customer.endsWith(searchString));
}

searchCustomer(['C000000123', 'C000000456'], 123); // "C000000123"
searchCustomer(['C000000123', 'C000000456'], 456); // "C000000456"
searchCustomer(['C000000123', 'C000000456', 'A00000001'], 1); //"A00000001"
```